# How do I get a correct backtrace for a custom error class in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, node.js, custom-errors

My understanding for the "right" way to make a custom Error class in JavaScript is something like this:

```
function MyError(message) {  
    this.name = "MyError";  
    this.message = message || "Default Message";  
}  
MyError.prototype = new Error();  
MyError.prototype.constructor = MyError;
```

(Code snippet mooked from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error.)

With NodeJS, if I try to check for an error of this type like:

```
var err = new MyError("whoops");
assert.ifError(err);
```

...the backtrace will show the context of the Error object I created at compile time to be the prototype for MyError, not the MyError object I created with "new MyError()".

Is there some way that I can get the correct backtrace data for the actual error, rather than the prototype?

Comment: You might be seeing the symptoms of a bug in V8:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60240
Or perhaps this one:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99341

Comment: I think I might have found how to do this: http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi

Comment: Setting the prototype to a new Error is quite nasty because it means that useful features like stack traces will be set to that line rather than the line you actually want.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We need to invoke the super function - captureStackTrace

```
var util = require('util');

function MyError(message) {
  Error.call(this); //super constructor
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor); //super helper method to include stack trace in error object

  this.name = this.constructor.name; //set our function’s name as error name.
  this.message = message; //set the error message
}

// inherit from Error
util.inherits(MyError, Error);
```

#### UPDATE:

You can use this node module to extend Error types easily
https://github.com/jayyvis/extend-error

Comment: Should probably use `util.inherits` rather than the deprecated `__proto__`.

Comment: @distilledchaos noticed that your suggested edit to use util.inherits() got rejected. Your edit is valid and required to improve the quality of this answer. so i just incorporated it. thank you.

Comment: @JayyVis why was it rejected?

Answer (score 3):

@Jay Kumar, has one good answer here. However, maybe here is another similar solution [here](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/15511f92e5216fa2624b)

```
module.exports = function CustomError(message, extra) {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  this.name = this.constructor.name;
  this.message = message;
  this.extra = extra;
};

require('util').inherits(module.exports, Error);
```

> Error.call(this) - creates another error object (wasting a bunch of time) and doesn't touch this at all

Since the `ECMAScript6` could be supported in the latest `Node.js` version. The answer under `ES6` could be refer to this [link](http://azimi.me/2015/09/23/high-custom-error-class-es6.html).

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.message = message;
    this.name = 'MyError';
  }
}
```

Here are test codes under `Node v4.2.1`

```
class MyError extends Error{
        constructor(msg, extra) {
                super(msg);
                this.message = msg;
                this.name = 'MyError';
                this.extra = extra;
        }
};

var myerr = new MyError("test", 13);
console.log(myerr.stack);
console.log(myerr);
```

Output:

```
MyError: test
    at MyError (/home/bsadmin/test/test.js:5:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bsadmin/test/test.js:12:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
{ [MyError: test] name: 'MyError', extra: 13 }
```

Comment: What version of Node are you running with the ES6 example?